# Set amount of starts to application

Tags: android

I have quite weird question.

Is it possible to set amount of application starts on single device?

*I mean, let user start application only 3 times and then forbid it.*

The only possible solution comes to my mind is using `SharedPreferences` and calculate the count there.

Can you suggest any other approach?

Comment: will not work, because if user clear the app data, count will be 0 again. You may need to keep the count somewhere else. ex call web service at the startup of the app and update it in the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do this. Except if you have a login and you can only use your email or phone number 3 times and check with the server. If you store the data on the device, you can reset the application data and the counter would start over, or just reinstall.

So you have to make some communication to a server, store email or phonenumber over there and check if it's used 3 times.

Comment: what's about SQLite? What if I store counter there?

Comment: Same issue, application data reset, and you database is empty.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences won't work because the user can clear the data anytime.

What you could do is every time the app is started make a call to your server and increase the counter there. That way you can restrict on the basis of the device ID and it is always going to work.